# django+html video tag broke pipe on Safari

Tags: django, html, video, safari

I have been stuck on this issue for days.

The output from console is:

```
[30/Dec/2015 04:12:38] "GET /static/home/background.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 1772089
[30/Dec/2015 04:12:39] "GET /static/home/background.mov HTTP/1.1" 200 286720
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
self.finish_response()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
self.write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 217, in write
self._write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 328, in write
self.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket
[30/Dec/2015 04:12:39] "GET /static/home/background.mov HTTP/1.1" 500 59
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 51895)
```

I want to play the video on browser using the h5 video tag

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="{% static "home/body.png" %}" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
     <source src="{% static "home/background.mp4" %}" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="{% static "home/background.mov" %}" type="video/quicktime">
     <!-- fallback -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
           QT_WriteOBJECT("{% static "home/background.mov" %}" , '320', '240', '');
     </script>
    </video>
</div>
```

The code is almost the same as the example given by Apple.

And I've tried the page on chrome, the background video plays well.
But on Safari, it always return broken pipe.

Can anyone help? Many thanks.